# Rails add class to active url link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my app in layout i have such code:

```
%li
   = link_to "Новости", all_articles_path(id: 1)
%li
   = link_to "Тест-драйвы", all_articles_path(id: 2)
%li
   = link_to "VIP-объявления", advanced_search_show_path(by_vip: true)
```

and for example if i go to url "all_articles_path(id: 1)"   i need to add class to link "active", but how could i do this?
i have only ideas with:

```
- if request.original_url.include? ("all_articles/1")
  = link_to "Новости", all_articles_path(id: 1), class: "active"
```

but i think that this is a bad idea, maybe there are any other more pretty solve of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a better way: [`active_link_to`](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to)

This gem is amazing - you just have to use the `= active_link_to "link", path()` helper, and it will give an active class. We used it in a commercial app, and it worked out of the box

It's better than the `current_page?` method by far

---

**Update**

As per the comments, conditional styling would be something like this:

```
<% if defined?(params[:by_vip]) || defined?(params[:other])  %>
  <% active_class = "active" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "your_link, "#", class: active_class %>
```

Yes, it's basic & it can be put into a helper, but I hope it shows you what you can do!

Comment: `= active_link_to "VIP-объявления", advanced_search_show_path(by_vip: true), :active => :exclusive
                  %li
                    = active_link_to "Недавние объявления", advanced_search_show_path(by_new: true), :active => :exclusive`    -    how to highlight one link but not two! ?

Comment: so what do you think ?

Comment: Morning - sorry about the delay in responding

Comment: So you've used `active_link_to` but it's highlighting both?

Comment: active_link_to  -  yes, when in link i have get params, it highlight both

Comment: Well that's probably because it's the same path (`/search`). Am I right or does `advanced_search_show_path` show different `url`s?

Comment: one url, but with different data

Comment: It's probably because it's hitting the same URL - what do you want to happen? You'd typically use this kind of styling either with JS (if it's the same URL), or with in-view styling?

Comment: "with in-view styling"  maybe so.... just that link's are in layout and i didn't know how to do

Comment: just that do for this two link as RSB answer.

Comment: It's up to you! Conditional styling would mean using an `if` statement to work out which class to put in the link element. Using current_page? will just bring back the same result as this gem, as you're loading it on the same page each time

Comment: Conditional styling, like what? `if params[:by_vip].present? = link_to..... class: "active"` or what?

Comment: unexpected '='
 class = "active"

Comment: Okay I just re-created the error. I think the problem is the `class` local variable is probably reserved. I've amended the code for you, which I've tested & sets the correct value

Answer (score 7):

Use rails' `current_page?` [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) for this

```
class: <%= "active" if current_page?(all_articles_path) %>
```

To use this approach in HAML you may use string interpolations:

```
class: "#{'active' if current_page?(all_articles_path)}"
```

Comment: If you have several links for which you should perform such check you could define helper method that wraps `link_to` and performs check of `current_page?`

Answer (score 0):

Better we write a helper method to know whether link is active or not to add a class:--

```
  = link_to "Новости", all_articles_path(id: 1), :class => is_article_link_active?(1) ? "active" : ""
```

Add following method to your helper file.

```
def is_article_link_active?(id)
  request.path.include?(all_articles_path(id: id)) 
end
```

Comment: and how to be if i have other_path/1 ?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 yes you pointed it right, my mistake. Now I have updated the answer, see it now.